# Why 'eval' in ruby is so slow?

Tags: ruby

In the ruby code below, the 'eval' is more than 10 times slower than 'def'.

I understand that 'eval' needs to parse the string, but I suppose it only needs to be done once in this example.

```
require "benchmark"
GC.disable

eval "def run1; 10_000.times { #{"$a[5]\n" * 10_000} } end"
def run2
    10_000.times { "#{"$a[5]\n" * 10_000}" } 
end

$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

puts "run1:"
puts Benchmark.measure { run1 }

puts "run2:"
puts Benchmark.measure { run2 }
```

Comment: Use single quotes on the outermost parts of eval'd string to stop it being interpolated (and thus different to the code you think you are benchmarking). Nick Veys answer shows you *how* it is different in detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not comparing equivalent functions.  `run1` ends up being a function with `$a[5]\n` 10,000 times in a single string, since that string interpolation happens as the string is built, before `eval` is called.  `run2` runs as one would expect.

To see the difference, toss `ruby-prof` into the mix:

```
require "benchmark"
require 'ruby-prof'

GC.disable

eval "def run1; 10_000.times { #{"$a[5]\n" * 10_000} } end"
def run2
    10_000.times { "#{"$a[5]\n" * 10_000}" } 
end

$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

puts "run1:"
RubyProf.start
puts Benchmark.measure { run1 }
result = RubyProf.stop
printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
printer.print(STDOUT)

puts "run2:"
RubyProf.start
puts Benchmark.measure { run2 }
result = RubyProf.stop
printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
printer.print(STDOUT)
```

edit: here are results (I removed the Benchmark calls to prune it down to basics)

```
(nick@monster)-(~/Desktop)
(523)⚡️ ruby derp.rb 
run1:
Thread ID: 2156059640
Fiber ID: 2163430960
Total: 484.962207
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
100.00    484.962   484.962     0.000     0.000        1   Integer#times 
  0.00    484.962     0.000     0.000   484.962        1   Global#[No method] 
  0.00    484.962     0.000     0.000   484.962        1   Object#run1 

* indicates recursively called methods
run2:
Thread ID: 2156059640
Fiber ID: 2163430960
Total: 0.265188
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 94.02      0.249     0.249     0.000     0.000    10000   String#* 
  5.98      0.265     0.016     0.000     0.249        1   Integer#times 
  0.01      0.265     0.000     0.000     0.265        1   Global#[No method] 
  0.00      0.265     0.000     0.000     0.265        1   Object#run2 

* indicates recursively called methods
```